# PHP file_get_contents is slow and return 500 Internal Server Error

Tags: php, curl, file-get-contents, rss-reader

I'm trying to read rss of a news agency site and get several options of all news to save in my database. so i used php functions as file_get_contents or cURl but it takes about a minute to get content of site and analyze it for seperating that parts of news I want.

This is a part of my code that I get datails of news from rss:

```
$rss = new DOMDocument();
$rss->load('http://isna.ir/fa/Sports/feed');
$feed = array();
foreach ($rss->getElementsByTagName('item') as $node) {
    $item = array ( 
        'title' => $node->getElementsByTagName('title')->item(0)->nodeValue,
        'category' => $node->getElementsByTagName('category')->item(0)->nodeValue,
        'link' => $node->getElementsByTagName('link')->item(0)->nodeValue,
        'date' => $node->getElementsByTagName('pubDate')->item(0)->nodeValue,
        );
    array_push($feed, $item);
}
$title = str_replace(' & ', ' &amp; ', $feed[0]['title']);
    $link = $feed[0]['link'];
    $category = $feed[0]['category'];
    $date = date('l F d, Y', strtotime($feed[0]['date']));
```

And in this part I use link of news to get a photo from original news page :

```
$context = stream_context_create(array('http' => array('header'=>'Connection: close')));

$f = explode("news", $link);
$photo_link = $f[0]. 'photo' .$f[1];

$ff = file_get_contents($photo_link, false, $context);
$f1 = explode('<div class="news-image">', $ff);
$f2 = explode('<h1', $f1[1]);
$f3 = explode('href="', $f2[0]);
$f4 = explode('">', $f3[1]);
$image = $f4[0];

echo '<img src="' .$image. '"></img>';
```

And this is the result most of the times:

```
Warning: file_get_contents(http://isna.ir/fa/photo/92040301515/مدافع-تیم-ملی-آلمان-از-فوتبال-خداحافظی-کرد) [function.file-get-contents]: failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error in /opt/lampp/htdocs/example8/reader.php
```

I used the cURL functions too, but not much better result obtained!

Comment: Have you tried urlEncoding the image page request URL?

Comment: if you got `500 Internal Server Error`, that means the file is not readable

Comment: @bystwn22 the URL works fine! You could actually test it before you comment!

Comment: @tlenss yes, url of iamge page is correct. it this site url of image page is relative to url of news page , for example if url of news page is http://isna.ir/fa/news/other url of image page is like http://isna.ir/fa/photo/other.
I used $f = explode("news", $link); $photo_link = $f[0]. 'photo' .$f[1]; for get image page url from news page url.

Comment: have you tried urlencode($photo_link) ?

Comment: @tlenss I edited my question for your comment.

Comment: You should try using SimplePie for parsing RSS feeds.
http://simplepie.org/

It has a caching system which should increase your website load time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```
<?php
  $photo_link = explode( "news", $link );

  $first  = $photo_link[0];
  $last   = str_replace( basename( $photo_link[1] ), urlencode( basename( $photo_link[1] ) ), $photo_link[1] );

  $photo_link = $first."news".$last;
  print_r( file_get_contents( $photo_link, false, $context ) );
?>
```

so your full code will be something like this

```
<?php
  $feed = array();
  $rss  = new DOMDocument();
  $rss->load( 'http://isna.ir/fa/Sports/feed' );

  foreach( $rss->getElementsByTagName( 'item' ) as $node ) {
    $feed[] = array(
      'title'     =>  str_replace( " & ", " &amp; ", $node->getElementsByTagName( 'title' )->item(0)->nodeValue ),
      'category'  =>  $node->getElementsByTagName( 'category' )->item(0)->nodeValue,
      'link'      =>  $node->getElementsByTagName( 'link' )->item(0)->nodeValue,
      'date'      =>  strtotime( $node->getElementsByTagName( 'pubDate' )->item(0)->nodeValue )
    );
  }

  $title    = $feed[0]["title"];
  $link     = $feed[0]["link"];
  $category = $feed[0]["category"];
  $date     = date( "l F d, Y", $feed[0]["date"] );

  print_r( $feed );

  $context  = stream_context_create(
    array(
      'http'  =>  array(
        'header'  =>  'Connection: close'
      )
    )
  );

  $f  = explode( "news", $link );

  /** My Code Starts **/
  $f[1] = str_replace( basename( $f[1] ), urlencode( basename( $f[1] ) ), $f[1] );
  /** My Code Ends **/

  $photo_link = $f[0]."photo".$f[1];

  $ff = file_get_contents( $photo_link, false, $context );
  $f1 = explode( '<div class="news-image">', $ff );
  $f2 = explode( '<h1', $f1[1] );
  $f3 = explode( 'href="', $f2[0] );
  $f4 = explode( '">', $f3[1] );
  $image  = $f4[0];

  echo '<img src="'.$image.'"></img>';
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try URL encoding the arabic part of the url

```
$urlParts = explode('/', $f[1]);
foreach ($urlParts as $idx => $urlPart) {
  $urlParts[$idx] = urlencode($urlPart);
}

$photo_link = $f[0]. 'photo' . implode('/', $urlParts);
var_dump(file_get_contents($photo_link));
```

Comment: As $f[1] has two parts that one of them is arabic, now this is a problem with first part of $f1[1] that it's format is like **/number/**.